# How do I determine if a browser has tabindex on div support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML4, tabindex was valid only on certain elements. In HTML5 and thus in newer browsers, tabindex can be used on most elements, including div elements.

In browsers with support, setting `tabindex="0"` on a div will cause a focus event to fire and sets the focus state on the div when it comes up in the tab order. Older browsers will ignore this as invalid.

How can I detect if a given browser has support for this feature so I can build in a fall-back?

Answer (score 2):

Just take a peak if div elements have the focus function...

```
function divTabIndexSupport(){ return 'focus' in document.createElement('div'); }
```